# cocos2d, how to see log messages on android studio?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, cocos2d-android

I'am trying to log by "CCLOG" but I don't see the log messages on logcat of android studio.

how can i see log messages on android studio? there is another log function?

Answer (score 2):

Use

> log("string")

or

> cocos2d::log

(if you haven't set cocos2d namespace as USING_NS_CC;)

Comment: Thanks you for your response,I try this, still don't working.